# MTurk: Best 2 out of 3 HIT creation/retrieval

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, mechanicalturk

#### Desired Result

I can retrieve the agreed upon answer value for a given HIT

#### The Problem

When I call

```
CLIENT.list_review_policy_results_for_hit(HITId=hit['HITId'])
```

to retrieve the results for a specific HITId from the mturk sandbox endpoint, the "Value" for the agreed answer is an empty string. I assume I am missing some sort of question mapping in the layout definition or create_hit() logic but the docs are really unclear on how this should work so I'm not even sure "list_review_policy_results_for_hit()" is the correct method for retrieving results.

#### Background

I'm working on creating a pipeline for uploading single question HITs where the turker is expected to rate the text on a binary scale as "quality" or "not quality". I want to evaluate each HIT with a "best 2 out of 3" ruling where the HIT is served to two turkers for review and an additional third turker if a tie-breaker is necessary.

I'm using the [SimplePlurality/2011-09-01](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HITReviewPolicies.html) review policy to handle the "2 out of 3" logic.

I am happy to include more information/code samples upon request but didn't want to bloat the initial post with unnecessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you haven't configured your ReviewPolicy correctly.

Can you please share the ReviewPolicy you're passing in as the HITReviewPolicy parameter in your CreateHIT request?

I've shared an example below. You would replace "your_question_id" with the identifier from your HIT.

Thank you

```
{
    'PolicyName': 'SimplePlurality/2011-09-01',
    'Parameters': [
        {
            'Key': 'QuestionIds',
            'Values': ['your_question_id']
        },
        {
            'Key': 'QuestionAgreementThreshold',
            'Values': ['66']
        },
        {
            'Key': 'ExtendIfHITAgreementScoreIsLessThan',
            'Values': ['100']
        },
        {
            'Key': 'ExtendMaximumAssignments',
            'Values': ['3']
        },
        {
            'Key': 'ExtendMinimumTimeInSeconds',
            'Values': ['86400']
        },
        {
            'Key': 'DisregardAssignmentIfRejected',
            'Values': ['T']
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was able to come up with a solution to my problem yesterday but it required me to abandon HITLayout and use QuestionForm instead. I couldn't figure out how to attach a question id to the HIT when creating it with a HITLayout specified. I'm going to go ahead and close this issue though since I was able to find an alternative solution.

Comment: You can set the question identifier using a HITLayout by setting the name attribute on the element where the Worker submits their answer.

e.g., if you create a new project using the Survey Link template, you'll see that the question identifier is "surveycode".

You can view and edit this by right-clicking on the survey code input and then selecting "Text Field Properties", or by selecting the Source view and looking at the HTML, specifically this part:

`<input class="form-control" id="surveycode" name="surveycode" placeholder="e.g. 123456" required="" type="text" />`